# typo3 extension delete cache and session

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

Hi I have typo3 extension which is a tiny shop.

What I want, is to delete the whole session and cache after a order.

How can I do this programatically in my controller?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

Your right, flush full cache is not good, I just reread my code ;) and I think it would be enought to clear the cockies.

I set the following values:

```
$order_data = array();
$order_data = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getKey('ses', USER_ORDER);
$order_data['firstname'] = $_COOKIE["firstname"];
$order_data['lastname'] = $_COOKIE["lastname"];
$order_data['email'] = $_COOKIE["email"];
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', USER_ORDER, $order_data);
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->storeSessionData();
```

what would be a good way to remove the FE user and the USER_ORDER data?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: It is a very bad idea to flush your entire cache at runtime initiated by user FE clicks. Not only it heavily slows down your system, if you have to do stuff like that, you should better fix your extension to not rely on such things. You're asking for an evil hack here.

To answer your question, the most brutal variant is "GeneralUtility::makeInstance(CacheManager::class)->flushCaches();". And no, please really don't do that. That's the opposite of "green-IT" so to say ;) Instead, get your tagging in the caches right, flush what you really need (flushByTag()), and have a look at USER / USER_INT processing.

For the Session stuff, the SessionManager class and the classes behind that should allow manipulating the session.

Comment: yes you are right, I added some more details and a more specific question above

Comment: I tried this:  `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->removeSessionData();` but it does not resolve my issues